# How to migrate from ext2 to ext4 when my filesystem is encrypted (LUKS)?

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, ext4, dropbox, luks

The reason why I am posting this question is that Dropbox has notified me (via e-mail), that it will soon no longer support ext2 for its desktop client.

I have a LUKS encrypted file system on top of an extended ext2 partition and I found the following "How To"s for migrating to ext4:

- https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/migrate-ext2-ext3-filesystem-to-ext4/
- https://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/11/convert-ext23-to-ext4/

However, the previous "How To"s do not mention anything about what to do if you have an encrypted file system such as LUKS. Is there no difference? If there is, how does one do this migration?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

- Back up all of your data no matter what you decide to do
- Boot to live CD
- sudo bash
- tune2fs -O extents,uninit_bg,dir_index,has_journal /dev/sda? The sda may be hd or
  something differant and the ? is the partition number.
- e2fsck -pf /dev/sda?
- sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt  Check for errors.
- edit the fstab on the root of the drive where the LUKS partition is to reflect the change in partition type.
- update-grub

The LUKS encrypted filesystem exists inside the ext2 partition, thus the migrating from one partition type to another should not matter as far as the data within as long as nothing goes wrong. Hence the backup. It is like taking the water in one glass and moving it to another as long as the proccess is comleted without error, the water should be the same in both amount and purity.